# How to maximize performance of Real-Time processing (Portaudio)

Tags: windows, audio, process, real-time, portaudio

I use the [Portaudio](http://portaudio.com/) library in my c++ real-time audio processing program.
I would like to know if it is possible to further offload and speed up processing in my main processing function, which is called as a [callback from the Portaudio high-priority thread](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html):

> The "callback" is a function that is called by the PortAudio engine
>   whenever it has captured audio data, or when it needs more audio data
>   for output.
>
> Before we begin, it's important to realize that the **callback** is a
>   delicate place. This is because some systems perform the callback in a
>   **special thread**, or interrupt handler, and it is rarely treated the
>   same as the rest of your code. For most modern systems, you won't be
>   able to cause crashes by making disallowed calls in the callback, but
>   if you want your code to produce glitch-free audio, you will have to
>   make sure you avoid function calls that may take an unbounded amount
>   of time to execute. Exactly what these are depend on your platform but
>   almost certainly include the following: memory
>   allocation/deallocation, I/O (including file I/O as well as console
>   I/O, such as printf()), context switching (such as exec() or yield()),
>   mutex operations, or anything else that might rely on the OS. If you
>   think short critical sections are safe please go read about priority
>   inversion. Windows amd Mac OS schedulers have no real-time safe
>   priority inversion prevention. Other platforms require special mutex
>   flags. In addition, it is not safe to call any PortAudio API functions
>   in the callback except as explicitly permitted in the documentation.

Target operating system: Windows 7 (both x32 and x64).

So, my questions:

1. Is it worth it to start my entire program as a high (or highest, real-time) **process**, like the following (using the [SetPriorityClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function):

   `SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);`
2. Is it worth it to decrease a priority of the GUI **thread** of my program, like the following:

   `QThread::currentThread()->setPriority(QThread::LowPriority);`
3. Is this good idea at all to maximize a whole process priority or decrease a GUI thread priority in any programs which have to do some real-time operations?
4. Is Windows 10 better than Windows 7 for real-time audio processing using the [ASIO driver protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output)?

Comment: That's a lot of tweaks, but before applying them you should define what exactly "realtime" is and measure existing performance / delays of your application to figure out whether you really need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth it to start my entire program as a high (or highest, real-time) process, like the following (using the SetPriorityClass WinAPI function)

It depends. SetPriorityClass is for the whole process while generally you'd want such a feature only for the audio thread. The PortAudio source code has a comment about it [here](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/git/source/master/src/hostapi/wdmks/pa_win_wdmks.c#ln6231). You would then certainly have to adjust the priority of the audio thread itself with [SetThreadPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority). [This thread on the PA mailing list has a lot of useful information.](https://portaudio.music.columbia.narkive.com/KHBBKuxg/experience-with-multimedia-class-scheduler-service)

The gist of it seems to be that it will really depend on the Windows way used to access your soundcard: ASIO, WASAPI, etc.